# Run Swift Package tests in release mode in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am trying to run the test target of a Swift package in Xcode in release mode **without generating an Xcode project**.

However, when I set the build configuration of the test scheme to release, the build fails because of a missing `-enable-testing` flag that has to be passed to the compiler when `@testable import` is used.

How can I add this flag in Xcode for a Swift Package? Note that the traditional build configuration options are not available because no Xcode project exists. Adding `-Xswiftc -enable-testing` as launch arguments for the test scheme does not work.

Comment: what xcode and swift versions do you use?

Comment: Xcode 12.0 (but I also had this issue with 11.x versions)

Comment: I can compile for release. Please share the error which you have?

Comment: Compiling for release is not the issue. But running package tests in release mode is not working because if you are using `@testable` imports, the error `MyLibrary was not compiled for testing` is emitted.

Comment: @Palle do you want to run your tests from terminal or inside Xcode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass swift compiler flags using the `swiftSettings` parameter of the [target(name:dependencies:path:exclude:sources:publicHeadersPath:cSettings:cxxSettings:swiftSettings:linkerSettings:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/target/3583314-target?changes=late_11) function in your SPM manifest file:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyPackage", swiftSettings: [.unsafeFlags(["-enable-testing"])]),
        .testTarget(name: "MyPackageTests", dependencies: ["MyPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

If on the other hand you want to run your tests from the terminal you can use `-Xswiftc` option like normally:

```
swift test -c release -Xswiftc -enable-testing
```

Comment: Great! Now it would be nice if `-enable-testing` was only provided when running the tests.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can no longer install the package as a dependency in an iOS project because unsafeFlags are forbidden there.

Comment: @Palle that's unfortunate. I am afraid that you have to stick with the second part of my answer: use terminal to run tests in release. At least for now.

Comment: Yeah I already did that before, but I was curious whether this is available in Xcode as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your tests for Release by removing `@testable` attribute of an `import` statement:

```swift
// MyPackageTests.swift
import XCTest
import MyPackage
...
```

It's partial solution because your tests don't have access to internal entities in your module but it works great for public ones.

Comment: This is not an option for me as I want to test stuff with internal visibility.