# Running Swift Package unit tests in release configuration: @testable module was not compiled for testing

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest, swift-package-manager, xctestcase

I would like to run unit tests in release configuration so that DEBUG is not specified. When I try to do this (from Xcode with an Xcode project file unlike in [Run Swift Package tests in release mode in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979632/run-swift-package-tests-in-release-mode-in-xcode)) I get a "module was not compiled for testing" build error for the module I've marked `@testable` (same as the linked question).

Is there a workaround I can use for the build scheme or configuration of my unit test target?

Answer (score 0):

To test anything in release builds, you'll need to make them `public`.

(In many languages, this is the only way for tests to access production code. Think of it as putting tests on the same playing field as any other external code.)